# How can I install PowerCommands for Visual Studio 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I have Visual Studio 2008 Express SP1 installed on my machine. I tried to install PowerCommands today, but it said that Visual Studio is not installed. Is there something I can do to get it to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 Express does not allow add-ins